# Open file from SharePoint from a winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint

i'm developing a local windows form application.

i'm trying to use the following code to directly start a word document located in SharePoint locally from the client side.

' System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("winword.exe", "https://sharepointsite.com/hr/word.docx"); '

it gave me a Microsoft Word Security Warning which says "that the information you exchange with this site cannot be viewed or changed by others."

Comment: could you post the code of your windows for application?

Comment: not sure if other parts is necessary. basically, a button click that will take in the url from a textbox and uses the method above to open a word file using the winword program at the client's side